# How can I get OS X Server.app 3.0.3?

Tags: macos, server

I have built a VMWare image of OS X Mavericks and added my archived copy of Server.app 3.0.1... What I really need is Server.app 3.0.3 because that's both the last version of the app that supports using the Xcode-server with Xcode 5... and has the bugs fixed in it that allow for Git access to a remote server.

Apple's App Store only offers me Server.app 4.x which isn't even compatible with Mavericks. How or where can I get the 3.0.3 version of the Server.app? (It's not on the apple developer website ever since it was put in the app store).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's off topic here but the links for the supported Mavericks version of server 3.2.2 are in this [Apple KB](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203137).

I think you can get 3.2.2 from the developer page still as well.

Comment: Nope. Goes to Server 3.2.2 which doesn't support Xcode 5.x. Thanks, though.

Comment: It should support Xcode 5. The description of Server 3.2.2 on the developer page reads, "Includes Xcode Server to enable continuous integration. Works with Xcode 5 to configure bots that automatically build and test your apps. Requires OS X Mavericks."

Comment: You are correct, thank you. Sadly, my original question didn't have enough information, though. I still have to use Xcode 5.0.2 while transitioning from GC to ARC. This was the last version that supported GC. Mavericks Server 3.0.3 still supported 5.0.2. Server 3.2.2 requires Xcode 5.1 or newer; Sigh.